# material 2 select with Angular2 not working

Tags: angular, select, angular-material2

Trying to use Google material 2 in my angular 2 application.
and using Reactive Form or Data Driven form.
my array is

```
states = [
    { value: 'KA', viewValue: 'Karnataka' },
    { value: 'GJ', viewValue: 'Gujarat' },
    { value: 'DL', viewValue: 'Delhi' }
  ];
```

and form builder is

```
this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({

      accountInformation: this.fb.group({
        fullName: ['', Validators.required],
        email: '',
        mobileNumber: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: '',
      }),

      currentAddress: this.fb.group({
        city: '',
        state: ''
      }),

    });
```

where `<md-input formControlName="city" placeholder="City*">` is working.

but  with formControlName is not working

```
<md-select placeholder="Select your state" formControlName="state"> 
                                                <option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.value"> {{ state.viewValue }} </option> 
                                            </md-select>
```

getting this error

```
No value accessor for form control with path: 'currentAddress -> state' ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
```

But not getting any error without `formControlName="state"` but the drop down is not proper.

Answer (score 0):

Possible actions when you see 1. If 'md-option' is an Angular component and it has 'value ..... error in console.

- Angular has not complied your component ( md-option) , and it doesn't mean anything more than a simple html tag , so you cannot bind anything to it , check bellow :

  1- You're trying to use a directive/component but you haven't declared it ( if you're using angular2 rc5< ) or you haven't put it inside your directives array ( if you're using angular2 rc5> ) .

2- You're using a component but you should have imported it's module inside your imports list of your app.

- Angular has compiled but:

3-If non if the above , then You're binging something to the component but that component is not expecting it , in another words , that component does not have that attribute in it's inputs array.

Comment: Thanks xe4Me, I am using the final release.and trying to use <md-select> where <select> is working.I have edit the question.now not able to bind with formControlName

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using `angular-material2` as question's tag says because you speak about "Google Material", but if you are actually using `angular-material2`, there is no `md-select` available for now.

Check out this link to know which component are release now : https://github.com/angular/material2

If you are using another lib than `angular-material2`, you may want to update your question to remove the `angular-material2` tag attached to not get irrelevant answers.